# Printing numbers from one list, not found in another

Tags: bash, shell

My first list contains:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 ....
```

List x contains:

```
5 10 15 20 ...
```

I want print any numbers in the first list that are not found in list x, i.e:

```
1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 11 12 13 14 16 17 18 19 .....

#!/bin/bash  
for i in $(seq 0  5 100)
do
echo $i
done
```

I want to print number does not contain the #for i in $(seq 0  5 100)

Comment: What is the question? How is the list stored? What have you tried so far?

Comment: this script show you all number that accept divid on 5 like (5-10-15...)
and I want to print number did not accept divid on 5 like (1-2-3-4-6-7-8-9-11...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
seq 100 | egrep -v "0$|5$"
```

basically it looks for and removes (`-v`) any line ending in 0 or 5.

Comment: Why? Surely it produces the same results as the answer you accepted?

Comment: sorry mark, I try it now, and it's the same result :)
thank you :))))

Comment: can you  provide me a brief explanation "seq 100 | egrep -v "0$|5$""

Comment: @Alivx `seq` starts with 1 if if the start field is omitted. So this prints from 1..100. That output gets piped `|` to the `egrep`. The `v` negates the given expression "0$|5$" means contains 0$ or 5$, where `$` is the end of line character. So literally "pipe each integer from 1 to 100 to egrep, and return all output which does not end in 0 or 5." (you can also type `man egrep` and `man seq` to learn more about them)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you have actual lists, or are just tying to generate a list that does not contain multiples of 5. If it's the latter, just do something like

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0..100}; do
  (( $i % 5 != 0 )) && echo "$i"
done
```

Where `%` is equivalent to `mod`.

Comment: but can you,  provide a brief explanation for "
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0..100}; do
  (( $i % 5 != 0 )) && echo "$i"
done

Comment: @Alivx {0..100} is bash expansion which is equivilent to `seq 0 100`. You can use `(())` to perform basic math operations in bash.

Comment: and "!" and "%" and "&&" what mean :)

Comment: @Alivx `&&` is logical `and` meaning something if a is true and b is true, then `a && b` is also true (as opposed to logical or `||`). `!` is the negation character, `!=` within `(())` means not equal. So literary it says "i mod 5 is not equal to 0 and print i" (so if i mod 5 is equal to 0 it will never get to the print i, because the expression can't be true)